# How to pass div attribute as parameter in dot html() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I have encountered is that the `textarea id` which I am passing is not working. I tried using `alert()` to check what `id value` it was taking, but the alert was empty. How should I go about fixing this?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){              
    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "Form1"){
            $("#text1").html("<textarea></textarea>");
            console.log("display text1 only");
            $("#text2").hide();
            $("#text1").show();   
        }
        else if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "Form2"){
            $("#text2").html("<textarea id='character1' rows='8' cols='30' maxlength='500' placeholder='Summary2' ></textarea><div id='textarea_feedback1'></div>"); 
            $("#text1").hide();
            $("#text2").show();
        }
        else if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "Select an Option"){
            $('#text1').hide();
            $('#text2').hide();
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: use val() instead of text() method in input elements....

Comment: Are you trying to pull info from the textarea, put data into it or dynamically create a textarea?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: Plz provide your HTML

Comment: I used val() but still problem is the same.Actually the id="character1" i am using in one more script (for limiting the character in text area ).now i am getting textarea but that limiting character script is not working.any idea where i am going wrong?

Comment: Here is fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/G7E79/

Comment: @tlindel I am trying to use the textarea id to run limiting character script.but Iam getting only textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your HTML for selectbox is like this,

```
<select id="select">
<option value='Select an Option'>Select an Option</option>
<option value='Form1'>Form1</option>
<option value='Form2'>Form2</option>
</select>
```

So script should change like this

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#select').change(function () {
            if ($('select#select').val() == "Form1"){
                $("#text1").html("<textarea></textarea>");
                console.log("display text1 only");
                $("#text2").hide();
                $("#text1").show();      
            }
            else if ($('select#select').val() == "Form2"){
                $("#text2").html("<textarea id='character1' rows='8' cols='30' maxlength='500' placeholder='Summary2' ></textarea><div id='textarea_feedback1'></div>"); 
                $("#text1").hide();
                $("#text2").show();
            }
            else if ($('select#select').val() == "Select an Option"){
                $('#text1').hide();
                $('#text2').hide();
            }
        }); 

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ducuk/1/edit)**

HTML:

```
<select id="select"> 
   <option value='Select an Option'>Select an Option</option>
    <option value='Form1'>Form1</option>
    <option value='Form2'>Form2</option>
</select>
    <div id="text1">

    </div>
    <div id="text2">

    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#select').change(function () {
          var value = $("select#select option:selected").val(); 
          if(value==="Form1") {
         var $text1 = $("#text1").html("<textarea></textarea>");
                $("#text2").hide();
                $("#text1").show();    
          }
       else if (value === "Form2"){
                $("#text2").html("<textarea id='character1' rows='8' cols='30' maxlength='500' placeholder='Summary2' ></textarea><div id='textarea_feedback1'></div>"); 
                $("#text1").hide();
                $("#text2").show();
            }
            else if (value == "Select an Option"){
                $('#text1').hide();
                $('#text2').hide();
            }
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: I have provide my code on fiddle.I want limiting character script to work.Please suggest me.

Comment: Since you are dynamically creating the textarea, while binding event to the character1, please use .on() of jQuery. It will bind event to dynamically created objects

Comment: Here is fiddle-jsfiddle.net/G7E79

Comment: there is no $('p') in the page. Also as i told before you must use .on() to bind event to the text area now. Please start another question if you want others to provide answer. The answer for current question is provided already. :)

Comment: Mmmmmm, I used .on() funtion but still I am getting  same problem .Its okay I will try to find some other way.Thanks for ur suggesstion..:)